# Filter Characterisation of Realcompact Spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

**My definition for Realcompact Space:** $X$ is realcompact if it can be embedded as a closed subspace of a product of copies of the real line.

I found the following characterisation of realcompact spaces in Gillamn and Jerison's 'Rings of Continuous Functions' $-$

> X is realcompact iff every prime z-filter with countable intersection property is fixed.

There, the proof is given in terms of ideals - a concept I'm not acquainted with. Nor am I acquainted with compactifications. So, is it possible to give a proof of this just in terms of filters and ultrafilters?

Comment: Engelking has yet another definition of real-compactness, and shows it is equivalent to being homeomorphic to a closed subset of some power of reals, and also the equivalence using the filter property (he does't call it $z$-filter, but just a filter in the poset of functionally closed subsets of $X$, which is the same thing).

Comment: In G&J they introduce ideals in $C(X)$ very early and in the beginning they show that when we have an ideal (in ring theory sense) $I$ of $C(X)$ we can define a filter of functionally closed subsets $Z[I]$ from it. With that book you cannot just start in the middle, it builds up an elaborate theory and framework that you have to get used to first. It's very elegant, really, but it makes it harder for beginners to just start with.

Comment: Engelking does use the theory on $\beta X$ from earlier in that chapter for the ultrafilter result. I don't see an easy way to avoid that completely, without essentially redoing that theory. So my advise: start from the beginning in G&J or learn compactifications from Engelking e.g. You'll need it anyway.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Thanks anyways!

Comment: It's *not* a shame, because without such background it makes no sense why people would *define* realcompactness in the first place. It follows quite naturally from compactifications and rings of functions considerations.